# Is there a way in the Rails Console to print a table of database contents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I'm looking for a clean and simple way to print in the Rails Console the contents of my 5 row database with 2 columns.

Any ideas? I Googled around but didn't find much.

Comment: I am a bit confused. What do you mean by _5 element database with 2 columns_?

Comment: Sorry, 5 rows, 2 columns

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should first use the [hirb](https://rubygems.org/gems/hirb) gem which provides a very pleasant way to print your tables columns.

1. Install *hirb* gem: `gem install hirb`
2. Add this gem to your project's *Gemfile*: `gem 'hirb'`
3. Go to your project's root folder and run Rails console: `rails c`
4. Enable *hirb* in the console:

   ```
   require 'hirb'
   Hirb.enable
   ```

If you want to limit the number of rows to display, you can do:

```
Model.limit(n)
```

For instance:

```
User.limit(5)
```

You can also specify the fields that you want to display using [select](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields):

```
User.select("name, email").limit(5)
```

Comment: After looking into `hirb`, I'd also recommend `wirble` and `awesome-print`. Related: http://iain.nl/customizing-irb-2010-edition

Answer (score 9):

You can also checkout [table_print](http://tableprintgem.com), it'll work something like this:

```
$ gem install table_print
$ rails c
> require 'table_print'
> tp Book.all
AUTHOR            | SUMMARY                         | TITLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Michael Connelly  | Another book by Michael Con...  | The Fifth Witness
Manning Mardale   | From acclaimed historian Ma...  | Malcolm X
Tina Fey          | Worth it. -Trees                | Bossypants
```

Comment: I love this gem. So easy to use. tbh I sometimes wish it was the default way rails console displayed tables!

Answer (score 2):

With `hirb`:

```
require 'hirb'
puts Hirb::Helpers::Table.render(ARRAY_OF_OBJECT_OR_HASHES)

# Examples:

puts Hirb::Helpers::Table.render([[1, "Terminator I"], [2, "Terminator II"]])

+---+---------------+
| 0 | 1             |
+---+---------------+
| 1 | Terminator I  |
| 2 | Terminator II |
+---+---------------+

puts Hirb::Helpers::Table.render([{ id: 1, name: "Terminator I" }, { id: 2, name: "Terminator II" }])

+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Terminator I  |
| 2  | Terminator II |
+----+---------------+

# specifying the order of the fields
puts Hirb::Helpers::Table.render([{ id: 1, name: "Terminator I" }, { id: 2, name: "Terminator II" }], fields: [:name, :id])

+---------------+----+
| name          | id |
+---------------+----+
| Terminator I  | 1  |
| Terminator II | 2  |
+---------------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check out `hirb` gem. Also worth trying is `wirble` and `awesome_print`.